# Finding an unitary matrix, $P$, and diagonal matrix, $D$, such that $P^{-1}AP = D$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. I need to find an unitary matrix, $P$ and diagonal matrix $D$, such that $P^{-1}AP = D$ (Or determine why those can't be found)

Now, for this to happen, $A$ must be a normal matrix, and this is true iff there's an orthonormal basis for $V$ composed by eigenvectors of $T$.

How do I do this in practice? Do I have to find the eigenvectors of $A$ and then apply on them Gram-Schmidt process?

Or should I first check that $A$ has $n$ different eigenvalues, since $D$ must be $D=\text{Diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Step 1:* Find the eigenvalues of $A$. In this case, they are $\{i,-i\}$.

*Step 2:* Find the corresponding eigenvectors (up to scalar multiplication). They are $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$. (In general, if an eigenvalue is repeated, find linearly independent and pairwise orthogonal eigenvectors corresponding to it, if possible—see the comment by @Omnomnomnom below.)

*Step 3:* Normalize the eigenvectors so that each has unit norm: $(2^{-1/2},2^{-1/2})$ and $(2^{-1/2},-2^{-1/2})$.

*Step 4:* Form a matrix $P$ having the eigenvectors as columns: $$P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{array}\right).$$
You can check that $P$ is unitary.

*Step 5:* Now let $D$ be the matrix having the eigenvalues in the diagonal: $$D=\left(\begin{array}{cc}i&0\\0&-i\end{array}\right).$$

*Step 6:* Check that $A=PDP^{-1}$.

Comment: Do I have to check it in the end? (Step #6)

Comment: When do the process can get failed? (My guess is that there are less than $n$ eigenvalues, right?)

Comment: Note: this process is sufficient when $A$ has no repeated eigenvalues, but may otherwise fail.

Comment: So the process work $\iff$ $A$ has no repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: Also, could you explain why is this process promise $P$ is indeed unitary?

Comment: The process _may_ work even if there are less than $n$ distinct eigenvalues. The process fails when an eigenvalue of multiplicity $k\geq2$ has less than $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you, but why is $P$ must be unitary?

Comment: $P$ will be unitary as long as the matrix $A$ is Hermitian. This is because eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal (see a proof [here](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~ars/MA106/week7.pdf)—see Proposition 7.7). In your example, the matrix $A$ is not Hermitian, yet the eigenvectors still happen to be orthogonal.

Comment: In general, the diagonalization process still works as long as the columns of the matrix $P$ of eigenvectors are linearly independent, but $P$ is not guaranteed to be unitary.

Comment: If $A$ is Hermitian with repeated eigenvalues, then it is possible to follow these steps and choose a $P$ that is not unitary.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can you give an example?

Comment: @triple_sec try the identity matrix

Comment: @triple_sec or for a less trivial example, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see. I added an extra instruction to Step 2 to circumvent this caveat.

Comment: @triple_sec it is not sufficient to have them be linearly independent; they must also be mutually orthogonal.  For example, with the identity matrix, we must disallow choosing $(1,0),(1,1)$, since the resulting $P$ will not be unitary.  Alternatively, once the linearly independent eigenvectors are selected, apply the Gram-Schmidt process (we can do this either to all eigenvectors simultaneously or within each eigenspace separately and achieve the same result.)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are right. Thank you for the clarification. I will add this, too.